# A problem about Doob's maximal inequality in $L^p$

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

$\{X_n,n\ge 0\}$ is a martingale and for a $\alpha>1,\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n\rvert^\alpha]<\infty, \forall n\ge 0$. Let $X_n^\ast=\max\limits_{0\le k\le n}\lvert X_k\rvert$. Prove that

$$\mathbb{E}[X_n^\ast]\le \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n\rvert^\alpha]^{1/\alpha}$$

Hint: $\mathbb{E}[X_n^\ast]=\int_0^\infty P[X_n^\ast>t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ and use maximal inequality for submartingale $\lvert X_n\rvert^\alpha$.

My solution:
I use the maximal inequality in $L^p$, which shows that $\mathbb{E}[(X_n^\ast)^{p}]^{1/p}\le \dfrac{p}{p-1}(\mathbb{E}[X_n^p])^{1/p}$. It is clear that $\mathbb{E}[X_n^\ast]\le \mathbb{E}[(X_n^\ast)^{p}]^{1/p}$ so we obtain the result.

But the proof of maximal inequality in $L^p$ use lots of the tools like Hölder's inequality and Fubini-Tonelli Theorem and some others. **I wonder if there is a more simple proof that use the hint?**

Comment: Do you want a simple proof of Maximal inequality?

Comment: Well, I think the maximal inequality in $L^p$ gives a much stronger result than what this problem asks for. So I want to know if there is a more simple solution for this "easier" question. Another try is use $\mathbb{E}[X_n^\ast]=\int_0^\infty P[X_n^\ast>t]\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^\infty P[(X_n^\ast)^\alpha>t^\alpha]\mathrm{d}t\le \mathbb{E}[X_n^\alpha]\int_0^\infty t^{-\alpha}\mathrm{d}t$. The integral in [1,\infty) can be calculated. But it is improper in $[0,1]$ so we may need another relaxation. But I cannot figure it out

Comment: Actually, in $L^p$ space, we assume $p\geq 1$.